# How to mention more than one user in single message when sending message in channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Currently, I have a chat-bot app that sends the message on the channel.

Also, it is capable of tagging a user. The below code is responsible for sending user mentioned message.

```
await turnContext.sendActivity(
 {
    text: `Hello <at>@${members[0].dispName}</at>`,
    entities: [
                {
                            type: 'mention',
                            mentioned: {
                                id: members[0].userName,
                                name: members[0].dispName,
                            },
                            text: `<at>@${members[0].dispName}</at>`,
                }
    ],
});
```

Further, How I can add **more than one user**?

**Note:** I have already tried using the loop but that’s creating separate messages - which I am not interested in

**Expected result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Motivation Taken from the conversation here

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/2360#issuecomment-822198968
- and further from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#constructing-mentions

The function which sends a message into the channel remains the same:

```
await turnContext.sendActivities([cardBody]);
```

the only this is the `cardBody` which needed to be modified:

```
let cardBody = {
    type: 'message',
    attachments: [
        {
            contentType:
                'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
            content: {
                type: 'AdaptiveCard',
                body: [
                    {
                        type: 'TextBlock',
                        size: 'Medium',
                        weight: 'Bolder',
                        text: 'Sample Adaptive Card with User Mention',
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'TextBlock',
                        text: 'Hi <at>user2</at>, <at>user1</at>',
                    },
                ],
                $schema:
                    'https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
                version: '1.0',
                msteams: {
                    entities: [
                        {
                            type: 'mention',
                            text: '<at>user2</at>',
                            mentioned: {
                                id: 'user2@mail.com',
                                name: 'user2',
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'mention',
                            text: '<at>user1</at>',
                            mentioned: {
                                id: 'user1@mail.com',
                                name: 'user1',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        },
    ],
};
```